# How to get sum of amounts from raw data having specific labels set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in sql like below:

```
Code Label Amount
X    this  100
X    this  300
X    this  500
X    last  700
X    last  800
```

The expected output is:

```
Code ThisAmount LastAmount
X    900        1500
```

I've tried below but didn't work as expected:

```
select t.code, sum(t2.amount) ThisAmount, sum(t3.amount) LastAmount
from table t
inner join table t2 on t.code=t2.code and t2.label='this'
inner join table t3 on t.code=t3.code and t2.label='last'
group by t.code
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: As a note, the reason your attempt didn't work is because you made a Cartesian product before aggregating. if you remove the aggregation you'll see you have 6 rows in total, tripling the value of `last` and doubling the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
   t.code
   , sum(case when Label = 'this' then amount end) ThisAmount
   , sum(case when Label = 'last' then amount end) LastAmount
from table t
group by t.code
```